# Windows 7 is not genuine after rolling back from Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, product-key, downgrade

A little background story:
I upgraded to Windows 10 while it was free, then rolled back to windows 7 within 30 days for the sole purpose of getting a “digital entitlement”. I didn’t use my PC for months, but today I thought of turning it on and see how my pc is doing. 
Problem:
Once at the desktop, a dialog box pops up saying "You may be a victim of software counterfeiting", and saw that my windows is not genuine and I need to apply a product key. I used ProduKey to get the product key of windows 7 I had before the upgrade, but using it gave me error 0xc004e003. I tried to apply the key again, same error. I looked up on microsoft (link:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/931276)  and tried their solution (Method C) which prompted me to Method G, to use the automated telephone system, which doesn’t appear as an option in my PC. 

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem? And how did the Windows10 recovery process loose the Windows7 product key?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This MS KB article has everything you need to know: [Get Help Activating Microsoft Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/950929). Also my guess (because you've not included any information about the actual system) is that your machine came with a pre-installed Windows 7 OS that had a generic key, so the one you're pulling is probably NOT a valid key, and instead it's an OEM key used for bulk installation, and can't be (re)activated.  If that's the case, you should have a Windows 7 OEM key on a sticker someplace, and that's your legit key for reinstalls/reactivations. Anyhow, call MS.

Comment: You should call the MS Activation Center.  "And how did the Windows10 recovery process loose the Windows7 product key?" This didn't happen.  Update your question after you call the activation center

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 well I looked for a sticker which I found one but wasn't a product key either (it didn't accept 0 as the first character). Tried to call the MS activation sender but it didn't work. Since my country does not have a phone code, shouldn't the number of the country code (mine is slovenian) work? Or are the numbers location-based (not phone-code based)

Comment: @Ramhound Tried to call them but somehow it got turned off within seconds. See upper comment.  I thought that by rolling back from windows10 fo windows 7 wouldn't ask me for the product key again.

Comment: "See upper comment. I thought that by rolling back from windows10 fo windows 7 wouldn't ask me for the product key again." - It shouldn't but since it does you have to activate the installation.  If its not automatically activating you have to activated by phone.

Answer (score 0):

Once you upgrade to 10 it appears that the key is converted to a 10 key with downgrade rights to Windows 7. So likely your key that came with the PC has changed in the installation. Calling Microsoft may help, but they may redirect you to your manufacturer for assistance. Having the key on the sticker with the machine is your best bet. Re-run activation and use the phone activation instead.

Comment: "Once you upgrade to 10 it appears that the key is converted to a 10 key with downgrade rights to Windows 7." -This is false.  This does not happen. A Windows 7 license cannot be converted to a Windows 10 license.  Windows 10 did accept Windows 7 licenses, and while that deal has now expired, the deal never involved converting a Windows 7 license to a Windows 10 license (you always received a digital entitlement to Windows 10)

Comment: Calling Microsoft will involved entering a challenge key, and receiving, a response code back. That is the correct solution.

Comment: @Ramhound  is there any other possibility to find the code rather than the sticker or calling MS activation center (I am calling at the slovenian number because my number is slovenian-my location has no phone code- but it doesn't work). Maybe it is somewhere in a registry key? I rolled back within the 30 day trial, which I think might have saved it in the windows.old folder somewhere

Comment: The sticker is the only license key you have.  Its not stored on the firmware like Windows 8+ license keys are.